# writeToFile how to tell when it is completed

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm doing some writing of data to my documents directory and I was wondering if there is a way to tell when my writeToFile method completes and the file I am creating has be fully created. Thanks in advance here is the method I am calling I am just looking for a way wether it is a delegate method or some other way to tell when this completes.

```
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
```

Nick

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The method `writeToFile:atomically` is "synchronous". It will write the file and then return `YES` or `NO` depending on wether the file was successfully written or not.

That means that the operation is complete as soon as the method returns.

```
BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
// Now, the operation is complete
// success indicates whether the file was successfully written or not
```

Comment: Is there a way to get an error log, if the saving is unsuccessful ?

Comment: @Patrick You can use the method [writeToFile:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:options:error:)

Comment: Swift version please !

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5:**

```
do {
    try data.write(to: path)
    // here's when write operation is completed without errors thrown
} catch {
    Swift.print(error)
}
```